# update_option not working in stand-alone PHP script

Tags: options, wp-load.php

I have a standalone PHP script in my WordPress theme's directory that I run once every hour through a cron job (or manually if needed). All other WordPress functions are working except the `update_option()` function.

A simplified version of my script looks like this:

```
require_once('/path/to/site/wp-load.php');

$value = my_function();
update_option('my_option', $value);
```

and in one of my theme's files, I am running the following code:

```
echo get_option('my_option');
```

Nothing is printed, and a `var_dump` shows that the returned value is `false`.

My `wp-admin/options.php` page doesn't list `my_option` either.

I'm at a loss, because below those lines, I am using the following WordPress functions to interact with my WordPress database successfully:

- get_posts
- delete_post_meta
- add_post_meta

Debugging my script, `my_function` returns a string (about 10 characters) and no errors are thrown with my PHP error settings at `E_ALL`.

Do I need to include other WordPress core files? I thought that `wp-load.php` was all you needed.

---

WordPress version: 3.7

Comment: Is the value set in the database?  If you modify the update_option() function directly (you can change it back later) and just dump out the $value param, is it being passed correctly?  If you do a function_exists on update_option, does it return true?

Comment: Nothing is being written to the database and my `wp-admin/options.php` page doesn't show `my_option` either. `function_exists('update_option')` returns true.

Comment: Go line by line, verify that $value is correct before update_option() is called.  If it is, go line by line in the function itself and see where it's failing.  It's "ok" to modify core on a testbed for strictly debugging as long as you never push a modified version to production.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it does't work for you, but the following works in the file `wp-content/test.php`:

```
<?php
// doesn't make difference to have this or not, for the rest to work
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 

require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' );

function my_function()
{
    return 'hello world';
}

$value = my_function();
update_option( 'my_option', $value );
var_dump( get_option( 'my_option' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this two line in your file top

```
 $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
 require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

It loads all of WordPress, but doesn't call wp() or invoke the template loader (used by themes) .

Comment: Please explain what the above code is doing, and why it is/should be working.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds you need some kinda of bootstrap for your code. WordPress has already bootstrap such as `index.php` or `wp-load.php` or even `wp-blog-header.php`.

This :

```
require_once('/path/to/site/wp-load.php');
```

is not recommanded because path can be modified. What you can do to have some bootstrap is :

```
// Load WP
$load = 'wp-load.php';
while( !is_file( $load ) ) {
if( is_dir( '..' ) ) 
    chdir( '..' );
else
    die( 'Could not find WordPress in this place!');
}
require_once( $load );
```

In this way you'll be able to load WordPress almost in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question but I will still comment on it.
Now you have multiple options: WP-CLI should work in almost all of the cases.
Another option is to create a custom plugin that hooks into 'init' event and it does something.